# Class object of subclass in super-class method

Tags: java, inheritance

Following super-class/sub-class relationship:

```
public abstract class A {
  public Class<? extends A> getSubClass() {
      Class<? extends A> clazz = ???
    }
}

public class B extends A {
  /* some implementation*/
}

public class Foo {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    A a = new B();
    a.getSubClass();
  }
}
```

Is there a way that `b.getSubClass()`returns the acutall sub-class type?

Comment: Uh...by replacing `???` with `getClass()`?

Comment: @Kayaman I should vote down, my own example was not right, I corrected it - sorry :-(

Comment: It's the same thing. Even though you could just call `a.getClass()`. Is this really your question, or is there something else you're trying to understand?

Comment: @Kayaman Now I am complete confused. I do Java development for years and thought I tested this and it did not work. Strange things happen if days are long. Thanks for your help, anyways!

Answer (score 0):

This

```
package test;

public class SubClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final A b = new B();

        System.out.println("Class: " + b.getSubClass().getName());
    }

    public static abstract class A {
        public Class<? extends A> getSubClass() {
            return this.getClass();
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        // No further implementation
    }
}
```

produces

```
Class: test.SubClass$B
```

Even in super-class methods, the actual class is the sub-class.